# C programming Finding min, max, and average

Tags: c

OK, I edited my program ***I am sorry if this is not formatted correctly (I don't know how to do that to make it easier to read for everyone :( I went through and fixed everything I could, but its still giving me errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define Max 1
#define Min 0

int getValidInteger(char promptString[], char errorString[], int lowerBound,
        int upperBound);
float averageIntegerArray(int height[], int count);

float printIntegerArray(char heading[], int values[], int count);
int findExtremeInIntegerArray(int minOrMax, int values[], int count);

//Get user input
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

//Get the number of scores
  int n = getValidInteger("Welcome to the Statisticamator! \n"
          "How many heights would you like to enter (1-100)?",
          "Number of scores must be 1 or higher\n", 1, 100);
  printf("N is %d\n", n);

//Read in information from the user
  int height[n];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    height[i] = getValidInteger("Enter height (0 to 100):",
            "Height must be between 0 and 100", 0, 100);
  }

//Prints average heights 
  printf("\n");
  printf("Average Height: %.2f inches\n", averageIntegerArray(height, n));

//prints minimum and maximum
  int min = findExtremeInIntegerArray(Min, values, n);    //ISSUE HERE TOO 
  printf("Minimum value is: %d\n", min);

  int max = findExtremeInIntegerArray(Max, values, n);
  printf("Maximum value is: %d\n", max);

  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);

}

//Average height in array
float averageIntegerArray(int height[], int count) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    sum += height[i];
  }
  return (float) sum / count;
}

//Get integer input from user
int getValidInteger(char promptString[], char errorString[], int lowerBound,
        int upperBound) {
  int input;

//Prompt user for input
  printf(promptString);
  scanf("%d", &input);

//Validate input

  while (input < lowerBound || input > upperBound) {
    printf("errorString");
    printf("\n");
    printf("promptString");
    scanf("%d", &input);
  }

  return input;

}
//Min and Max values
int findExtremeInIntegerArray(int minOrMax, int values[], int count);

  int Extreme = values[0];

  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)         //THIS IS WHERE IM HAVING 1 ISSUE
          {
    if ((values[i] < Extreme && minOrMax == Min) || (values[i] > Extreme && `enter code here`minOrMax == Max)) {
      Extreme = values[i];
    }

  }
  return (Extreme);
}
```

Comment: _throw my computer_ :D

Comment: `printf("Your minimum number is: %d inches \n");`: you didn't supply arguments to match the `%d` in there. Same for the maximum-line below.

Comment: If you can't understand and rectify that warning message then perhaps throwing your computer isn't such a bad idea...

Comment: Why do people just down vote and irritate people?

Comment: probablythyrgetirritatedfirstbypostswithcodetheycannoteasilyfollowbecauseofpoorformatting

Comment: For future reference the first part of the error message `main.c:38:38: ` tells you the line number and column where the error occurred.

Comment: I know I'm not a good programmer, but if it wasn't formatted correctly, or written correctly then just don't answer the post. Im very new to this and I am trying.

Comment: My first C program was a tragedy.  It had to find all the possible paths through a user supplied maze.  C is a great language... welcome aboard.

Comment: jobless ...... lol! Thanks!

Comment: @JDilworth It's still not formatted correctly. You can [edit] it.

Comment: @JDilworth it's not a matter of good/bad programmer, just one of a little consideration for SO contributors who answer the questions.  Poor formatting might not seem that important to you, but it's a great help for those who may consider looking at you problem.  If your presentation is unclear, the skilled and experienced developers on SO will just downvote your question and move on to another that requires less effort up-front.  That applies to all posters, irrespective of their level of expertise.

Comment: I don't understand how it was "poorly formatted".

Comment: @JDilworth it is just copy-pasted. No indentations, opening brackets after for cycle must be on the same line. Use more stricter compiler (sth like -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wbad-function-cast -Wconversion -Wwrite-strings -Wstrict-prototype) to see exactly why.

Comment: oh, well thank you. I have to use NetBeans for school right now (I know, i hate this IDE) anyways, thank you for explaining all of this to me :)

Comment: I APOLOGIZE TO EVERYONE IF THIS IS NOT FORMATTED CORRECTLY, I AM SERIOUSLY STUMPED... IF ANYONE KNOWS WHERE MY ISSUE IS CAN YOU PLEASE HELP ME OUT? THANK YOU

Comment: Is `int findExtremeInIntegerArray(int minOrMax, int values[], int count);` supposed to have a `{` at the end instead of the semicolon?

Answer (score 4):

You should add a parameter after the " in the following two statements.

```
printf("Your minimum number is: %d inches \n");
printf("Your maximum number is: %d inches \n");
```

If you wanted to print 3 variables you would have three format specifiers.

```
printf("Your maximum number is: %d inches %d feet %d miles \n", inches, feet, miles);
```

The format specifier is a place holder.  What the warning is telling you is that you have not given it a number to format in that place.  %d is hanging out by itself.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. Im trying to understand this, but its just not clicking.    Can you give me an example of adding the parameter?

Comment: ok.. thank you. So I think i understand... printf("Your minimum number is: %d inches \n", Min);       ???

Comment: Yes but you would probably have to do some math in your loop to track what the minimum value is... as well as an accumulator to be able to calculate the average... but you are on your way.)

Comment: @Chux... Thank you so much for your help! And thank you for helping me understand how to post correctly on this site.  :)

Comment: @JDilworth Thanks for the thanks, but better not to say thanks and up-vote useful answers and accept a quality answer should that occur.